# gTTS (Google-Text-to-Speech) Error: Audio gets saved but does not play automatically

Tags: python, google-text-to-speech

This is my code for text-to-speech conversion:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
tts=gTTS(text="Hello World",lang="en")
tts.save("hello.mp3")
os.system("mpg321 hello.mp3")
```

I already installed gTTS through the command prompt(pip install gTTS).

But when I'm running the above code in python 2.7, I am not getting any error but nothing is happening either.

I can't hear anything.

I am using Windows 10

Can you please advise what should be done?

Comment: Do you have mpg321 installed? Is hello.mp3 created?

Comment: yes..hello.mp3 is created.

Comment: But, then is it possible for the sound to play as soon as the program is runned?

Comment: Or should I add additional code for that?

Comment: os.system("mpg321 hello.mp3") is supposed to do that but you might not have mpg321 on your path. What happens when you run `mpg321 hello.mp3` from console in directory where hello.mp3 resides?

Comment: Nothing happens...

Comment: I tried to install mpg321 using "pip install mpg321"....but I got this error " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpg321 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mpg321"

Comment: No info about unknown command? Then I've got no clue whats up.

Comment: I've missed your last reply. So you do not have mpg321? I'm not familiar with the tool but on Windows there seems to be no official binaries and it is not clear whether it can be even compiled for this platform. Maybe use original mpg123 instead?

Comment: Even when I used mpg123, it's not working...

Comment: Is the file playable in any other mp3 player?

Comment: Yes, it is playable

Comment: just delete the mpg321 from your code and it should work.

Comment: that means you didn't install the command. To play auido, this works for me `os.system("afplay b.mp3")`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. The problem was in the last line. Instead of `os.system("mpg321 hello.mp3")`, use the following:

```
os.system("start hello.mp3")
```

Since I save the text-to-speech converted audio in the working folder, it would suffice me to mention just the name of the audio inside the `os.system`.

Generally if you want to play an audio from the system, you would need to use this line:

```
os.system("start /thepathyouwant/filename")
```

The final **working** solution code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
tts=gTTS(text="Hello World",lang="en")
tts.save("hello.mp3")
os.system("start hello.mp3")
```